# Analice la frase "la Biblia se queda pese a lo que pasa"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Yo he tomado o he encontrado esta frase: "la Biblia se queda pese a lo que pasa".

Es del himno "La Biblia es fiel" por Haldor Lillenas. En inglés es "The Bible Stands".

Es en el estribillo de este himno.

El estribillo: "La Biblia es fiel aunque montes caigan y **se queda pese a lo que pasa**; 
yo me planto firme en el fundamento que la Biblia es."

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que analicemos exactamente?  Si intentas hacer un análisis primero, podemos mejor entender lo que quieres.

Answer (score 3):

Por partes:

- "Lo que [pasa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX)" se puede interpretar como lo que se transforma, lo que muere, lo que termina, lo que deja de existir (acepciones 33, 40, 45, 55)... o simplemente como lo que ocurre (acepción 52).
- "[Pese a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SmGC3aC#6LBKXNu)" es una locución que significa "a pesar de".
- "[La Biblia] se [queda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UloraJw)" significa que la Biblia no se va a mover de donde está.

Básicamente la frase **quiere decir que la Biblia va a seguir ahí aunque todo lo demás cambie**.

---

Como traducción, creo que es bastante rebuscada y seguramente sea una adaptación local hecha así para ajustarse a la métrica de la canción. El original deja el sentido mucho más claro:

> The Bible stands though the hills may tumble,
>   It will firmly stand when the earth shall crumble;
>   I will plant my feet on its firm foundation,
>   For the Bible stands.

Una traducción más literal sería:

> La Biblia aguanta en pie aunque las colinas tiemblen,
>   aguantará firme cuando la tierra se derrumbe;
>   Plantaré mis pies en sus firmes cimientos,
>   porque la Biblia aguanta.